# What is happening physically when we vary the $\alpha$ in the impedance boundary condition $u + \alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$?

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

Say are considering acoustic waves in a domain $D$ filled with water and with an impedance boundary condition

$$
u + \alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0, \quad x \in \partial D,
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose we start with $\alpha = 0$, which gives us a Dirichlet boundary condition, and somehow we are able to vary $\alpha$ so that it gradually goes from $0$ to a very large number, which essentially means we now have a Neumann boundary condition.

What would this situation correspond to physically? Does it mean we are changing the material outside the domain of water in some way? If so, what are the materials before, during, and after we vary $\alpha$? If not, what is the actual physical interpretation of this process?